# Checking if file path extension exists logic. Scala

Tags: scala

I have a method that looks like this:

```
val extension = if (keepExtension) {
      if (!FilenameUtils.getExtension(path).isEmpty) s"${FilenameUtils.getExtension(path)}." else ""
    }
    else ""
```

Is there a better way to write this?

In short, sometimes I want files to keep their extension before zipping (so `somefile.csv` would become `somefile.csv.zip`) and if there is no file extension I want to just add the extension (so `somefile` becomes `somefile.zip`) and I want to handle the extra period correctly if there is or is not an extension.

Notice the period. I can't just write `if (keepExtension) FilenameUtils.getExtension(path) else ""`. The tests would fail.

**EDIT**

This is what I needed:

```
val extension = if (keepExtension && !FilenameUtils.getExtension(path).isEmpty) s"${FilenameUtils.getExtension(path)}." else ""
```

Comment: Looking at the docs it seems that `getExtension` returns an empty String if there is no extension. So your `isEmpty` check and the inner `if` is essentially obsolete.

Comment: There's another extension after that.

Answer (score 1):

Edited as I missed the extension separator.

Isn't your actual aim then to just create the following?

```
val fileName = (if(!keepExtension) FilenameUtils.removeExtension(path) else path) + ".zip"
```

Maybe some more details on how you then plan to use that extension value you defined might help.

Comment: It's missing the dot included in the OP

Comment: the dot is YUGE